# What does 'aye' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, word-meaning

So, I'm actually a native American English speaker, but I can't figure out what 'aye' could mean in this song.

> "At the sad decree...they'll depart for **aye**", "for alas I'm doomed...for **aye**".
>
> [The Lost Soul by Doc Watson Family](http://lyrics.wikia.com/The_Doc_Watson_Family:The_Lost_Soul)

I already know **aye** can mean "yes", but it doesn't make sense here. I looked it up and [could only find the Scottish "always/still"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aye) (which is archaic, on top of that), but I still have doubts, especially since the speakers are from Southern USA (North Carolina).

So, does the phrase "for aye" really mean "for always; forever" or is it something else? Thanks for any input! :D

Comment: As a Scot, I can assure you that this use of "aye" is most definitely NOT archaic. This information is from the horse's mouth as it were.

Comment: [According to this entry at Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aye) `aye` means "always or forever" in this context. Note its similarity to the English contraction "e'er" which is most often used in poetry. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, *aye* almost certainly does mean *always.* For one thing it makes perfect sense contextually. Moreover, the connection with Scottish actually makes a lot of sense. We learn from Morag, in another answer, that *aye* is still used in Scotland. Even if it weren't, archaic English or Scottish would not be out of place in this song.

The Watson Family lived in the Appalachian Mountains, a region settled by Scottish and Irish immigrants. Difficulty of travel kept them functionally isolated, and the pre-radio music of that region is known for strong ties to old ballads of Scotland, England and Ireland. Here's a great radio piece about this history: http://hereandnow.wbur.org/2014/10/01/wayfaring-strangers-book

The corpus of Appalachian folk music also includes a lot of references to political roles that never really existed in the U.S. - Lords, ladies, knights, kings, etc.  Examples abound here: http://www.contemplator.com/america/index.html

Answer (score 6):

I am British, living in Scotland for 35yrs, background in literature and languages. I can assure you it means 'always' here. Sometimes pronounced 'I' and sometimes ay like bay. We sing a hymn at church which contains it and the latter is the pronunciation used by the Scottish congregation there, though I would normally read it as 'I'. There may be parts of the country where people still say aye meaning always, but it is a dialect word, not used nationally in everyday speech.

Comment: In the words of the old aphorism, "a language is a dialect with an army and a navy.” and the King's Scots had both an army and a navy.   Scots shares a common ancestor with English, but they parted ways around 1100, and were re-merged when the King's Scots was deprecated for geopolitical reasons in the 17th Century,  "Aye" in the sense used in the question is therefore a continuance of use of Scots, rather than use of a dialect of Late Modern English.  It remains in use nation-wide in Scotland.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the phrase "for aye" really means "for always; forever" in this context.

Here's the [Chambers Dictionary definition](http://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=aye&title=21st) : "always; still; continually", derived from 13th Century Norse.

Aye is also defined at length in the [Dictionary of the Scots Language](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/aye)

Here are some contemporaneous Scots examples.

"He'll aye be in trouble".

"She'll aye hae a job on her hauns unless she can get thon scunners tae gie her mair ay the time o day".

Comment: I'm a native-speaker of both Scots and  English.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what Bob Jarvis said, e'er, which is a contraction of 'ever' would make sense contextually. *"Through me among the people lost for ever."* (line from Dante's Inferno. *"Through me among the people lost for aye."*)